# GNU mingw compiler error: sh: gcc: command not found

Tags: c, gcc, gnu, gcc-warning

I have downloaded the GNU compiler using the instructions online. Whilst compiling, I keep on getting the following error:

*sh: gcc: command not found*

I have tried to search online, but I have has no luck. Does anybody know why this is occurring, or how to fix it?

P.S
I have the mingw folder saved in `C:\mingw` and I am using the `msys.bat` compiler as suggested online which is located in `C:\mingw\msys\1.0`. The source .c file I am trying to compiler is located in `D:\cfiles\task1`.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Did you include mingw directory into your PATH variable?

Comment: No I haven't. I will try it now, as suggested by Ehsan. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.mingw.user/44061) I found that solves this exact issue by modifying a line in the `fstab.sample` file (in my case this is the name). To summarize, add `mount` to the following line in `fstab.sample` like this

```
c:/MinGW/       /mingw   // Suggested* default line

mount c:/MinGW/ /mingw   // Fixed the "gcc:command not found" error for me
```

*Suggested by MinGW/MSYS [installation guide](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started) and seems to be present by default in the file these days. This is an *alternative* solution and modifying path variables works.

Comment: This answer saved my sanity. The only change I had to make is mount c:/MinGW/ /mingw32 , but I bet some config scripts might be the way agrus specified.

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on Computer. Properties. Advanced Settings. Add a new path to path variable. It should be the place of bin.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have managed to get to system variables, but when I click to edit the path, it does not give me the option to add a path. It gives me the option for a new path but requests a path name and value. Is this how I should do it?

Comment: You should edit PATH double click on it. Don't change anything in it . Just move the cursor to the end and put a ';' and type the path to bin.

Comment: I only have options for Path and PATHEXT. I tired to add 'C:\mingw\msys\1.0;'  at then end of th elist in Path but that didn't work, I still keep getting the same error. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Maybe just a matter of restarting your computer. If it did not work go to the bin directory and see if gcc.exe exsits maybe you have not installed mingw completely with all packages

Comment: My platform is not windows(it used to) if you insist on using gcc compiler download virtual box and ubuntu disk image and use a virtual machine. It is so much easier to use utilities like make and gcc in a linux environment , Otherwise use Microsoft Visual Studio. Another better alternative for mingw is cygwin which is more popular

Comment: thanks for your help. Last question, Should I be looking for gcc.exe in msys, or in the main mingw folder? If I cant find it, do I just need to download it from the website and add it to the bin?

Comment: just search it. If you did not see it in search list be sure you have not installed mingw correctly and click on mingws icon on the desktop. Just know that cygwing is a better *NIX simulator which offers more packages and easier environment to work. I personnaly used both Mingw and Cygwin when I was working on windows but I prefer Cygwin . Visit www.cygwin.com

Comment: Right thanks for your help Ehsan. I tried to rate you up but I don;'t have enough points. Hopefully it'll help others though. Thanks for your time and effort. The problem was that the msys gcc.exe wasn't downloaded.

Comment: So I thought I had it working, and now I've run into more trouble. I am trying to work with the complex.h library, which is the only reason I am using mingw, but for some reason, it doesn't let me work with it. I noticed that it was not included in the libraries, and so I copied the complex.h file in. However, I still get the message:

/usr/include/complex.h:25:20: _mingw.h: No such file or directory

Can you suggest anything here?

Comment: @Ehsan cygwin is only *better* if you consider "better" to mean "offers more packages"; the word "better" is usually superfluous and/or meaningless and can go the other way too. For example, mingw is *better* because it produces binaries that don't depend upon massive cygwin bloatware, a larger house is better because it has lots of space, a smaller house is better because there's less to clean, heat and cool, a larger aircon/heating unit is better because it can heat/cool more, a smaller unit is better because it uses less power and takes up less space... See? Don't use the word "better".

Answer (score 0):

You know downloading a header file from internet isn't suitable because maybe that header file depends on other libraries and header files. So you should solve dependencies manually. Check [this url](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mingw-org-wsl/ci/4.0.0/tree/include/_mingw.h) and post errors.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to use complex.h for its math functions forget about it and use math.h. Code :

```
#include <math.h> /* In c++ : #include <cmath> */
// Use math.h functions
```

[A usefull link for math.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/)